# Spatial dimensions in Many-Worlds interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

As I understand it, in the many worlds interpretation there is only the wavefunction evolving in Hilbert space, and each non-interacting part of this configuration space experiences itself as a separate world.

However, doesn't this mean that our physical reality consists of infinite dimensions in order to contain this physically real configuration space?

Answer (score 0):

To answer myself: No, all of the different "worlds" can coexist in superposition within the same 3D universe. We simply need an infinite (or at least very large) number of dimensions in order to contain the information about what is happening in all of these different worlds.